# Select the app that will load the map

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Im opening a map like this:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%@,%@", destLat, destLong];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

Is there any way to choose with which app will open the map? For example, Safari, or the maps app, or Tom Tom app...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should use one of the iPhone URL schemes. There is a pretty hefty list [available here](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes).

Note that you should first check if the application you want to launch is available before using a certain URL scheme.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to get the list of the ones avalaible for the user?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the syntax is:

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]], which returns true if a certain scheme can be opened.

Answer (score 2):

If Tom Tom exposes some url scheme you can try that one. Otherwise the default url scheme handlers are "hard coded" to the system and you can't override / change them i.e. "http:" will be always opened by Safari except for "maps.google.com" domains, etc.