# Open map with safari or maps

Tags: iphone, ios

I need the user to choose if he wants to open the map with Safari, or the map app, but the thing is that wether I do this:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f&dirflg=d", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude, destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

or the same with:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"maps://maps.google.com/maps?
```

They both open maps ( I guess is because Safari redirects to maps)

Is there any way to force safari to open it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select the app that will load the map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790038/select-the-app-that-will-load-the-map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can force Safari to open a maps.google.com URL. [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html) says that Safari will open it if Maps isn't available, but otherwise it sends those URLs to Maps. It's not even Safari that sends the user to Maps, but rather the UIApplication class. You can see the difference if you specify an `https` protocol -- that way it will open Safari and then kick you into Maps.